# How can I check whether a row has ben deleted

Tags: java, sql, database, interface

I'm working on a Java program that reads data from an SQL Database.
I want to be able to know when a row has been deleted from the Database, so my program can process that piece of information.
I tried looking for logs or anything but I wasn't able to solve the problem so far.
Does anyone know how I can read out which row IDs have been deleted?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thank you for the fast replies, short clarification:
I'm using MSSQL, MySQL and MariaDB Servers, periodically checking would be sufficient, there's no need for a "real time reaction" from the program. The database will be edited from an external source I don't have control over. I'm only reading data by sending SQL Queries from my Java program.
The main goal would be to check like once a day if any data has been deleted. If so which ID in which table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Some more information would be useful. What DB are you using? Do you want to perform this check periodically or right after a deletion? Can't you do this check in the same place where the row is deleted?

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS in use, there's pretty much two approaches: Making use of the information you used for `DELETE` (mysql and most rdbms), or using `RETURNING` (postgres, maybe others). JDBC will provide an `int` return from `executeUpdate` specifying the number of rows affected, but not what rows they are. You might be able to grab something like this with a temptable or by using transactions for a non-instant response. You can also use triggers to "offload" deleted data to a table before truly deleting them.

Comment: Create a table DELETED_ROWS and a trigger wich is called on every deleted record. Inside the trigger write some data (like ID and current timestamp) to DELETED_ROWS. In your Java program you can query this table and you know which rows were deleted.